# WPF Events Tunneling

Tags: wpf

Consider the following code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplicationWPF.CommandsWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="CommandsWindow" Height="300" Width="300" PreviewMouseUp="Window_PreviewMouseUp" MouseUp="Window_MouseUp" >
    <StackPanel Name="StackPanelNew"  Background="Beige" PreviewMouseUp="Window_PreviewMouseUp" MouseUp="Window_MouseUp">
        <Button Name="BTNNew"  VerticalAlignment="Center" PreviewMouseUp="Window_PreviewMouseUp" MouseUp="Window_MouseUp">
            <Label Name="LabelNew"  BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="4" PreviewMouseUp="Window_PreviewMouseUp" MouseUp="Window_MouseUp">
                <TextBox PreviewMouseUp="Window_PreviewMouseUp" MouseUp="Window_MouseUp">HELLO</TextBox>
            </Label>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

When I click the label, it's previewkeyup does not fire for label but when I click the textbox it fires for all the controls from Window to textbox(including label).

Why is it so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason , in my own thoughts

That is because , it is impossible to determine whether Mouse up was originated by label click or Button click , try with right clicking on the label.

Comment: Yes, right clicking the label does work.WPF event routing is very complex !

Answer (score 1):

Nah, it might seem complex from the start, but it's not.

Explanation to your situation is quite straightforward: When you left-click a `Button` it [captures mouse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.capturemouse.aspx) input and prevents further event propagation over the subtree. Not the case when you click on the `TextBox` (nobody captures the mouse here).

Comment: In your answer, it should be "when you left click a Button....".Because it happens only in the case of left click. When I right click, everything behaves in the usual way, I mean, all elements fire tunneling events and then bubbling events.

Comment: That's right. Because only left button click is captured by the Button. Updated the answer